# iOS Stop all current processing within for loop on dismissal of ViewController

Tags: ios, for-loop, uiviewcontroller, terminate

I am using the code below which is called within a `UIViewController` with embedded `UITableView`.
It goes through a list of places, creating `NSURL` & passing this to `NSXMLParser`. Everything works with this as expected.

However, I would like for if the user clicks on a back button, that not only is the `UIViewController` dismissed and the user returned to the previous `UIViewController` which I have already, but I would like for the processing associated with the `for loop` that is occurring within `-(void)getInfo` and `NSXMLParser` to be terminated immediately if indeed it is still running.

In most scenarios, the processing would be complete, and this will not be an issue, however, there are possible instances where this may take a little longer, and I do not wish for the code to continue to run after pressing back, as there is then no need for the data, and thus would simply be wasting resource, and potentially jam the UI when returning to the previous UIViewController due to the processing of the multiple `NSURL` s.

```
-(void)getInfo{
    NSDictionary *places = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"places" ofType:@"plist"]];
    NSArray *placescc = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:places.allKeys];
    __block NSUInteger placewaiting = placescc.count;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary *savedLocs = [[defaults objectForKey:@"savedLocs"]mutableCopy]; //got savedLocs
    NSDictionary *thisLoc = [[savedLocs objectForKey:_LocId]mutableCopy]; //got this Loc

    lastInfoCount = 0; // set default
    if ([[thisLoc objectForKey:@"Infos"]count]){
        lastInfoCount = [[thisLoc objectForKey:@"Infos"]count]; // set saved count if we have one
    }

    for (NSString *place in placescc) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://url.com/%@/%@",place, LocIdString]];
            NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [parser setDelegate:self];
                [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
                [parser parse];

                placewaiting = placewaiting-1;
                if (placewaiting == 0){

                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                    lastRefresh = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSDate date]];
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using NSOperationQueue and NSBlockOperation then you can cancel the operation in dealloc (or possibly viewWillDisappear) and within the block executing on GCD thread test isCanceled and exit / skip UI update. However you must ensure weak references to view controller or the execution block will retain the controller. Something like this:

```
// @property(nonatomic,weak) NSBlockOperation *backgroundOperation;

+ (NSOperationQueue*)operationQueue
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static NSOperationQueue *operationQueue;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    });

    return operationQueue;
}

- (NSOperationQueue*)operationQueue
{
    return [[self class] operationQueue];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.backgroundOperation cancel];
}

- (void)getInfo
{
    NSDictionary *places = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"places" ofType:@"plist"]];
    NSArray *placescc = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:places.allKeys];
    __block NSUInteger placewaiting = placescc.count;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary *savedLocs = [[defaults objectForKey:@"savedLocs"]mutableCopy]; //got savedLocs
    NSDictionary *thisLoc = [[savedLocs objectForKey:_LocId]mutableCopy]; //got this Loc

    lastInfoCount = 0; // set default
    if ([[thisLoc objectForKey:@"Infos"]count]){
        lastInfoCount = [[thisLoc objectForKey:@"Infos"]count]; // set saved count if we have one
    }

    // Ensure previous operation finished
    [self.backgroundOperation cancel];

    NSBlockOperation *op = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];
    self.backgroundOperation = op;
    __weak NSBlockOperation *weakOp = op;
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    [op addExecutionBlock:^{
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://url.com/%@/%@",place, LocIdString]];
        NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        if (weakOp && !weakOp.isCancelled)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [parser setDelegate:weakSelf];
                [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
                [parser parse];

                placewaiting = placewaiting-1;
                if (placewaiting == 0){

                    [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
                    [weakSelf.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                    lastRefresh = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSDate date]];
                }
            });
        }
    }];

    [[self operationQueue] addOperation:op];
}
```

Note that weakSelf, weakOp and backgroundOperation property will auto-null when their referenced objects are released so if UI update code in block ever executes after view controller dismissed weakSelf.tableView/activityIndicator will be null and a no op. In your case since most of the work is in retrieving and parsing the data synchronously so that won't be aborted but the above code means the view controller will be released immediately and UI updates on the view controller become no-ops.

Comment: Thanks for this. I shall have a go with making these changes. You did comment saying the retrieving and parsing won't be aborted. Is there anyway I could do that? In particular I am thinking stop the retrieval altogether? For speed I have it set so it will use the 64 threads available. But clearly if the data isn't needed, I would prefer tomterminate the requests with immediate effect if possible? Would welcome your views? Many thanks again.

Comment: I would suggest a switch to an asynchronous use of NSURLConnection. You can then use -[NSURLConnection cancel] to abort the transfer. There are some 3rd party libraries such as AFNetworking that may make this easier. I have built my own network i/o library over the years to handle this kind of scenario.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will take a look at the options there.

Comment: Hi Mark. Sorry for the delay in coming back. I have sat down today and looked at this code. In my original code, I used `for (NSString *place in placescc)` however, looking at the code block you suggest, I don't see how is `place` populated within the `op addExecutionBlock`. I may well be missing something completely, and am sorry if that is the case, but would you be so kind as to enlighten me? Many thanks.

Comment: Correct - I left out the outer loop - sorry! This changes things a bit since you will then have multiple operations running concurrently but you could not bother saving the individual operations in ivar(s) and use -[NSOperationQueue cancelAllOperations]. So remove backgroundOperation property and references, replace [self.backgroundOperation cancel] with [[self operationQueue] cancelAllOperations] and wrap all the code starting with NSBlockOperation *op = ... in the for loop. This assumes you are only using the operation queue for this process otherwise the cancel could abort other stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! At least I wasn't losing my head! I did wonder if it was a case of bringing the for loop back, as I couldn't see any other way. What you say seems to make sense, so I shall have a go and will let you know how I get on. I don't believe the operation queue will be doing anything else, so the cancelAllOperations sounds like it is prime candidate. Thank you once again.